# How to press keys in Selenium 2 (a.k.a WebDriver) with Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, firefox, selenium-webdriver, keypress

I'm using Selenium WebDriver to visit a website that often times out a lot. For some reason, the only way to get the site loaded properly after a time out is to clear the history and reload the page. Is that possible with Selenium? To bring up the history in Firefox is CTRL + SHIFT + DEL; How can I enter these keystrokes and then reload the page? I've looked through the docs which lists a few methods for pressing keys, but so far I haven't gotten them to work. Any help would be so greatly appreciated.

Example code:

```
begin
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
driver.navigate.to "http://example.com/"
driver.find_element(:id, 'loginname').send_keys 'username@hotmail.com'
...


rescue Exception
#Some sort of code to press CTRL + SHIFT + DELETE, ENTER
#or clear the history in another way
retry
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is really weird. I don't understand how it can depend on browser history.

Still, to refresh the page there is a `#refresh` method.

About keys, as far as I know WebDriver can only send keys to HTML element.